# How to pass Thymeleaf object from base page to ajax generated page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a registration process that has substeps and I have individual HTML pages for these substeps for easier management. Now I have a "base page" which is the container. The following div is where I load the subpages.

```
<div id="substeps" th:object="${stepFourForm}">
</div>
```

and I load the substeps using ajax

```
$('#substeps').html(data);
```

How can the loaded substep page retrieve the `stepFourForm` object on the base page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `div` content before loading substep page. And you can do it using thymeleaf fragments.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/example-url",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#substeps').html('');
        $('#substeps').html(data);

    }
});
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping("/example-url")
public ModelAndView example() {

    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("substep1  :: content");
    return view;
}
```

Example fragment html name **substep1**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:dt="http://www.thymeleaf.org/dandelion/datatables">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div th:fragment="content">
    --some content
</div>

</body>
</html>
```